# How does a node with return self work?(Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

So this is the node part of a singly linked list. I am not supposed to change the way it has been coded, but I dont know how this type of structure would work. Self.link cannot event be accessed to point towards another part of the list. Does anyone know how to work with such a Node class?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, inval=None):
        self.val = inval
        if inval==None:
            self.link = self
            print (self)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.val == None:
            return ''
        else:
            return str(self.val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Comment: This code is garbage so if you're not supposed to change the way it's coded, you're out of luck here.

Comment: Make a new class. Why must you use others' code while you can make one?

Comment: I don't know, it was posted by my professor. I mean if you remove the if inval ==None or add an else condition it should work like normal linked lists. But he did put a  ## DO NOT MODIFY: ALREADY IMPLEMENTED on the top of this, and I am hoping that he knows what he put in if its a mistake on his side then it sucks for me... as a student.

Comment: We can't explain why your professor made these mistakes.  From the sound of your comments, you already understand the problem with the code, so there is not really any question to answer here.  You'll need to ask the prof about it.

Comment: "*Self.link cannot event be accessed to point towards another part of the list.*" I don't understand your conclusion here. Why can't `self.link` be accessed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nothing in the `Node` implementation that would prevent you from using it in a `List` class. Just pretend that the final three lines of `Node.__init__()` don't exist.

Here is one way to use the professor's `Node` in your `List`.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, inval=None):
        self.val = inval
        if inval==None:
            self.link = self
            print (self)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.val == None:
            return ''
        else:
            return str(self.val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def prepend(self, val):
        head = Node(val)
        head.link = self.head
        self.head = head
    def append(self, val):
        if self.head is None:
            self.prepend(val)
        else:
            p = self.head
            while p.link is not None:
                p = p.link
            p.link = Node(val)
            p.link.link = None

    def __str__(self):
        result = '<'
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            result += str(p) + ', '
            p = p.link
        result += '>'
        return result

l = List()
l.append(3)
l.prepend(2)
l.append(4)
l.prepend(1)
l.append(5)
print(str(l))
```

And here is the result:

```
<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, >
```

Comment: Then the `Node` would accept a link at init time.  This impl makes no sense.  -1

Comment: No, the `Node` accepts a value at link time, not a link. Does it make more sense now, embedded in a running program?

Comment: No, it doesn't make any more sense.  The implementation has no coherent interface for the link.  At the very least, you would set a link attribute to `None` in init and document that it needs to be overridden.

Comment: Looking at OP's post and comments, we aren't allowed to touch `Node.__init__`, so we can't set the link attribute to anything there.

Comment: Right, which is the source of the OP (understandable confusion).  I'm saying they need to ask the prof this because it's not really an on-topic question for the site - "How to use this broken code?".

Comment: I think Robs solution is perfect. Thank you Rob, I will ask the professor why he gave us such a different version of linked list to work with. But honestly vim the code was not broken in any way, just needed another way to work with. I don't know who gave Robs answer a negative one, but he solved it perfectly.

Comment: @siddharthapachhai  If it helped, you should consider to leave an upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation of the linked list, which has a slightly different styled node.

```
class LinkedList:
    lock = 0
    if lock == 0:
        tempdata = None
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.head = Node() # Node at the head of the list
        self.current = None # Node currently pointed to by the iterator
        self.count = 0

    def insert(self, value):
        NewNode =Node(value)
        NewNode.link = self.head
        self.head = NewNode
        self.count += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.head
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.current = LinkedList.tempdata
        if LinkedList.lock == 0:
            self.current = self.head
            LinkedList.lock += 1
        else:
            pass
        if self.current.value == None:
            LinkedList.lock = 0
            raise StopIteration
        previous = self.current
        self.current = self.current.link
        LinkedList.tempdata = self.current

        return previous   



    def __str__(self):
        result = ''
        self.current = self.head
        while self.current.value is not None:
            if self.current.link.value is None:
                result += str(self.current.value)
            else:
                result += str(self.current.value) + ' -> '
            self.current = self.current.link
        return result

    def search(self, value):
        found = 0
        temp = None
        out= False
        while found == 0:
            try:
                temp = LinkedList.__next__(self)
                if temp.value == value:
                    found += 1
                    out = temp


            except StopIteration:
                pass
        return out



    def delete(self, value):
        print ("hwta")
        found = 0
        temp = None
        head = self.head
        if head.value == value:
            print ("Head")
            if head.link.value != None:
                self.head = head.link

            else:
                self.head = Node()
        else:
            while found == 0:
                try:
                    temp = LinkedList.__next__(self)
                    if temp.link.value == value:
                        if temp.link.link.value == None:
                            temp.link = Node()
                            break
                        else:
                            temp.link = temp.link.link
                            print ("tails")
                            break
                except StopIteration:
                    pass



    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

#a = Node()
#print(a)                  # 3
#b = Node("Hullo")
#print(b)                  # 'Hullo'
#lst = LinkedList()
#lst.insert(2)
#lst.insert(3)
#lst.insert(5)
#lst.insert(6)
#lst.insert(7)
#lst.insert(6)
#print(lst)                # 5 -> 3 -> 2
#c = lst.search(2)
#print(c)                  # 3
#print(c.link)             # 5
#lst.insert(2)
#print(lst.head.link.link) # 3
lst.delete(6)
print (lst)
#print(next(lst))          # should print 5, 3, 2 on separate lines
#lst.delete(2)
#print(lst)                # 5 -> 3
#print(len(lst))           # 2
#for u in lst:
#    print(u)
```